# Error while serving the app with --prod in angular

Tags: angular7

Angular app is running fine with `ng serve`,but error shown when run with `ng serve --prod`

> ERROR in : Invalid provider for the NgModule 'ɵngrx_modules_effects_effects_b in E:/TrainingPortal/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/effects.d.ts' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [ɵngrx_modules_effects_effects_f in E:/TrainingPortal/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/effects.d.ts, EffectSources in E:/TrainingPortal/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/effects.d.ts, Actions in E:/TrainingPortal/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/effects.d.ts, ?null?, ...]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
.
.
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { appReducer } from './state-management/app.reducer';
import AppEffects from './state-management/app.effects';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
.
.
import { PdfReaderComponent } from './shared/components/pdf-reader/pdf- 
 reader.component';


import { AsyncPipe } from '../../node_modules/@angular/common';
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    .
    .
    ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    .
    .
    Ng5SliderModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(AppEffects),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: environment.production // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    })
  ],
  providers: [ApiService,DatePipe,MessagingService, AsyncPipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
 export class AppModule { }
```